# On how to compute $H_*(\Omega^2 S^{n+2}, \mathbb Z/2)$ and its Steenrod operations

Tags: homology-cohomology, spectral-sequences, loop-spaces, cohomology-operations

I've been trying to understand the calculation of $H_*(\Omega^2 S^{n+2},\mathbb Z/2)$ as an algebra, together with the dual Steenrod operations on it which lower the degrees. I've spent many hours looking for references, and it seems to me that the only place I can find such a computation is in *The Homology of Iterated Loop Spaces* by May, Cohen and Lada. The thing is that their computation relies on very technical machinery like Dyer Lashof operations and Nishida relations, and they actually show way more than what I just need. Is there any place where I can find a more accessible reference, or should I try to rewrite the whole computation of Cohen translated for my particular case ?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went into the details and eventually realised that the computation is made really easy by the following theorem of Borel :

Let $\Omega B\to PB\to B$ be the path fibration of a simply connected $H$-space $B$. Let $f_1,f_2,\dots\in H_*(\Omega B;\mathbf F_2)$ be a locally finite familly of elements such that $\sigma(f_1), \sigma(f_2),\dots$ form a simple system of generators of $H_*(B;\mathbf F_2)$. Then, $$H_*(\Omega B;\mathbf F_2)\cong \mathbf F_2[f_1,f_2,\dots]$$
((Switzer, theorem 15.60))

It applies in this exact version, with $B=\Omega S^{n+2}$ and $f_i=Q(Q(Q(\cdots Q(x_0))))$ $i$-times, where $x_0$ is the fundamental class of $S^n$ and $Q$ is the only Dyer Lashof operation